# Animate RenderTransform in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rendertransform

I've got a question regarding animations for WPF in C# code!
I have an handler function for the MouseWheel event. It just checks if you 'zoomed in' or 'zoomed out'. Just have a look at the code, the important line here is the 4th line, where the RenderTransform is set.

```
    private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
        var factor = (e.Delta > 0) ? (1.1) : (1 / 1.1);
        currrentScale = factor * currrentScale;
        mNetworkUI.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(currrentScale, currrentScale);
        var pos = e.GetPosition(mNetworkUI);
        mNetworkUI.Width = ZoomPanCanvas.ActualWidth / currrentScale;
        mNetworkUI.Height = ZoomPanCanvas.ActualHeight /currrentScale;
        var dummyTransform = new ScaleTransform(factor, factor, pos.X, pos.Y);
        var offSet = new Point(dummyTransform.Value.OffsetX, dummyTransform.Value.OffsetY);
        mNetworkUI.ViewModel.Network.SetTransformOffset(offSet);
    }
```

I kept the rest of the function in the code for completeness.
What I want to do, is to **animate this change of the RenderTransform**!

I already tried to use a Storyboard (with UIElement.RenderTransformProperty set). Best result was a not-animated change of the RenderTransform (but it was not the same result as this 4th line from the code achieves).

Maybe you can help me, I already tried a few suggested methods from the other questions here.

**Edit:**

Here's the non-working attempt and at first the chenged code from above:

```
    private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
        var factor = (e.Delta > 0) ? (1.1) : (1 / 1.1);
        currrentScale = factor * currrentScale;
        ///mNetworkUI.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(currrentScale, currrentScale);
        Helper.Animations.RenderTransformAnimation(mNetworkUI, new ScaleTransform(currrentScale, currrentScale));
        var pos = e.GetPosition(mNetworkUI);
        mNetworkUI.Width = ZoomPanCanvas.ActualWidth / currrentScale;
        mNetworkUI.Height = ZoomPanCanvas.ActualHeight /currrentScale;
        var dummyTransform = new ScaleTransform(factor, factor, pos.X, pos.Y);
        var offSet = new Point(dummyTransform.Value.OffsetX, dummyTransform.Value.OffsetY);
        mNetworkUI.ViewModel.Network.SetTransformOffset(offSet);
    }
```

And it follows the static helper function:

```
    public static void RenderTransformAnimation(FrameworkElement element, Transform newTransform) {
        MatrixAnimationUsingKeyFrames anim = new MatrixAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        var key1 = new DiscreteMatrixKeyFrame(element.RenderTransform.Value, KeyTime.FromPercent(0));
        var key2 = new DiscreteMatrixKeyFrame(newTransform.Value, KeyTime.FromPercent(1));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, element.RenderTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(anim);
        sb.Duration = AnimationDuration;
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

It always throws an exception on the sb.Begin() call, telling me, something was not ok with my 'PropertyPath'. I don't know how to do it :(.
I mean, there is no way to directly create a "TransformAnimation", right? Only MatrixAnimations are available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've provided a simple animation of a `ScaleTransform` below.  In the interests of providing a 'minimal' example, I only adjust the scale; I don't do any of the offset calculations that you're doing based on mouse position.  You should be able to figure out where to go from here:

```
private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var factor = e.Delta > 0d ? 1.1d : 0.9d;

    var t = mNetworkUI.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
    if (t == null)
    {
        mNetworkUI.RenderTransform = t = new ScaleTransform(1d, 1d)
                                         {
                                             CenterX = 0.5d,
                                             CenterY = 0.5d
                                         };
    }

    var oldScale = (double)t.GetAnimationBaseValue(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty);
    var newScale = oldScale * factor;

    //
    // Make sure `GetAnimationBaseValue()` reflects the `To` value next time
    // (needed to calculate `oldScale`, and for the animation to infer `From`).
    //
    t.ScaleX = newScale;
    t.ScaleY = newScale;

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
                    {
                        To = newScale,
                        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d),
                        DecelerationRatio = 0.5d,
                        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
                    };

    //
    // Use `HandoffBehavior.Compose` to transition more smoothly if an animation
    // is already in progress.
    //
    t.BeginAnimation(
        ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, 
        animation, 
        HandoffBehavior.Compose);

    t.BeginAnimation(
        ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty,
        animation,
        HandoffBehavior.Compose);
}
```

Comment: You get a +1 if you explain why you explicitly set `t.ScaleX = newScale`. That's overridden by the animation, isn't it? Btw, you don't need to specify the `oldScale`. The animation can figure that out.

Comment: Yes, the scale values are overridden by the animation, but only for the duration of the animation.  Once the animation ends, you want the property to still have the `To` value.  But yes, you can specify *just* the `To` value or *just* the `From` value and let the animation figure out the other.

Comment: Why not wrap those two animations in a storyboard? Otherwise, this seems right to me.

Comment: You certainly can use a storyboard, and I usually do when coordinating more than two animations (especially if their timelines aren't identical).  In this case, I felt it just added a layer of complexity.

Comment: Tweaked answer a bit to smooth things out if an animation was already in progress.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! I will try that, when I come home from work today!

Comment: Ok, what I get is the normal behaviour if I scroll the MouseWheel slowly, but if I scroll faster I see an animation :)! Do you know why that happens?

Comment: I'd guess the size delta isn't big enough for the subtle animation to be noticeable.  Try commenting out the `DecelerationRatio` to see if the motion becomes more pronounced--I added that so the animation slows as it progresses.  You can also try reducing the duration.  These settings looked pretty nice on my test project, but you may need to tweak them for your own project.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that as well, but it didn't work. I found out, what caused the effect now though :). Had to omit the two lines where you manually set the ScaleX and ScaleY! Thank you for your help!

Comment: That actually changes the behavior a bit.  Might be better to just set `From` to `oldScale` rather than letting the animation infer the value, which appears to be the cause.